# How do you copy text from a diagnostic float window in Neovim/Lunarvim?

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

I'm on Lunarvim and I can check the line diagnostic with `gl`.
But I don't know how to go there with the cursor and copy the text, the mouse doesn't work either.

Comment: I haven't used lunarvim, but maybe the diagnostic popup window is set to be non-focusable. So do you can not move your cursor to popup window and copy text. However, you can try  command `lua vim.diagnostic.setqflist()`, which should populate your quickfix list with diagnostic and you can copy from there.

Comment: Yes, thanks it works, you can add it to the answers if you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely that the diagnostic popup window is set to be non-focusable. So you can not move your cursor to the popup window and copy text. However, you can try command `lua vim.diagnostic.setqflist()`, which should populate your quickfix list with diagnostic and you can copy from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the diagnostic popup window to focusable by passing `{ focusable = true }` to `lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()`

Docs for [vim.diagnostic.open_float](https://neovim.io/doc/user/diagnostic.html#vim.diagnostic.open_float())

The options for `vim.diagnostic.open_float` is the same as `vim.diagnostic.open_floating_preview`

Docs for [vim.diagnostic.open_floating_preview](https://neovim.io/doc/user/diagnostic.html#vim.diagnostic.open_floating_preview())